# Disable Django to keep only Django Rest Framework for Vue

Tags: django, vue.js, django-rest-framework, vuejs3

for a school project, I have to use Django and Vue.
Django to provide an API and Vue for the frontend.

They are two separate projects that we have mix.
For example, I type `my-site/clients`, it gives me the list of the clients in json format (API). But if I type `my-site/home` it gives me a Vue page.

I tried to run the two servers on the same port, but that is not compatible (Django want to display a page when it has to Vue to display it). So I was thinking to disable the Django to only keep Django Rest Framework for the API.

Is it possible ?
Thank you !

Comment: You can't use DRF without Django, for sure

Comment: @JPG Ho Okay ...
But here is a way to avoid Django to display page or if it has not the page, keep Vue displays the pages ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usually, you'd run the two servers on different ports locally. For example, Django on 8000 and Vue on 8001. And then you'd call your Django API from your web application using it's port, e.g. localhost:8001/api/my-method.

Your production configuration will differ depending on your setup, but with Nginx, for example, you can point `/api/` to one port and everything else to a different port.

Comment: Okay, thank you !
I think I will use differents ports